# POST request Not returning DATA to Express i.e. to server

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a form validation for *Email and Password* if that matches it will replace with some other code and shows the **Email and password** in serverconsole. Flow of program is onclick() of submit it goes go to **main.js** and executes **newFunction()** it returns **POST** data to server i.e **Server.js** and replace the html content.But in my case the **/Login** url is handled but the email and password are not entering to my if condition in **Server.js***
        `if( emailid == 'abc@g.com' && password == '123' )
        {
         console.log('Success'+emailid+password);
        }`

I have tried all the POST request handlers but it is not working.

### Home.html

```
     `<!--Login LogOut-->
    <div class="container" id ="Loginchange">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"  style="padding-center:20px; border-right: 3px solid #84b1aa;"><!--For middle line-->
                <!--Existing user-->
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block active" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#existingUser" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="existingUser">
                    Existing User

                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="existingUser">
                    <div class="card card-body"><!--Start of existing in button-->
                        <!--Alert with X-->
                        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                            <strong>Hello Arkodian</strong> Please Log in.
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!--Existing Form-->
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="LoginEmail">Email address</label>
                                <input  type="email" class="form-control" id="LoginEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Email Id" required>
                                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="LoginPassword">Password</label>
                                <input  type="password" class="form-control" id="LoginPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                            </div>
                          <!--  <div class="form-group form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                            </div> -->
                            <button onclick="newsFunction()" id="Login" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`
```

### main.js

```
  function newsFunction() {
     var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     Request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (Request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if (Request.status == 200){
             let  loginHtml = Request.responseText;
             let  ul = document.getElementById('Loginchange');
             ul.innerHTML =loginHtml ;
             console.log(loginHtml);
           }
       }
     };

     Request.open('POST', '/Login', false);
     Request.send({
        extid: document.getElementById('LoginEmail'),
        extpsd:document.getElementById('LoginPassword')
       });
    }
```

### Server.js

```
 var express = require('express');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var app = express();
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended :false}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post('/Login',function(req,res){
   var emailid = req.body.extid;
   var password = req.body.extpsd;
    if( emailid == 'abc@g.com' && password == '123' ){
        console.log('Success'+emailid+password);
      }
    else {
       console.log('user not found');
      }
    var loginHtml = `<p>Hello World</p>`
    res.status(200).send(loginHtml);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this stringify the data object and add header `"Content-Type": "application/json`

```
function newsFunction() {
     var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     Request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (Request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if (Request.status == 200){
             let  loginHtml = Request.responseText;
             let  ul = document.getElementById('Loginchange');
             ul.innerHTML =loginHtml ;
             console.log(loginHtml);
           }
       }
     };

     Request.open('POST', '/Login', false);
     Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
     Request.send(JSON.stringify({
        extid: document.getElementById('LoginEmail').value,
        extpsd:document.getElementById('LoginPassword').value;
       }));
    }
```

Comment: @siddharthreddy what are the values you are getting for 
  console.log(req.body.extid, req.body.extpsd);` on server.js

Comment: the email id and password from html and enters **main.js** for response to send to **server.js** their it goes to **/Login**, but it is not entering the if statment, don't no why I think because of this code where data is not sent from here to **server.js**
 `Request.send(JSON.stringify({
        extid: document.getElementById('LoginEmail'),
        extpsd:document.getElementById('LoginPassword')
       }));`

Comment: @siddharthreddy in server.js file before the if condition try to log the values of req.body.extid, req.body.extpsd. And check if they are undefined or null?

Comment: @siddharthreddy i have update the answer too give try

Comment: you said correct it return's null `{},{}` but tried your code it is not entering in to if statment.

Answer (score 0):

`It got worked when I added` **.value** `to the JSON object.`